# ¿Como ejecutar webdrivers selenium de manera aleatoria?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Buenas una pregunta muy curiosa supongamos que tengo el webdriver de chrome, firefox, Safari. ¿Existe la posibilidad de hacer que se ejecuten de manera aleatoria cada vez que ejecute el script?
¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.sitioweb.com/")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes simplemente crear un iterable con los drivers (referencias a las clases `webdriver.x`) deseados y hacer uso de [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
import random
from selenium import webdriver

drivers = (webdriver.Firefox, webdriver.Safari, webdriver.Chrome)
driver = random.choice(drivers)()
driver.get("https://www.sitioweb.com/")
```

Si se necesitan pasar argumentos al constructor (como la ruta al driver) podemos hacer algo como:

```
import random
from selenium import webdriver

drivers = (
    {
         "driver": webdriver.Firefox,
         "kwargs": {'executable_path': '/Users/drivers/geckodriver'}
    },
    {
         "driver": webdriver.Safari,
         "kwargs": {'executable_path': '/Users/drivers/chromedriver'}
    },
    {
         "driver": webdriver.Chrome,
         "kwargs": {'executable_path': '/Users/drivers/safaridriver'}
    }
)

rand_d = random.choice(drivers)
driver = rand_d["driver"](**rand_d["kwargs"])
driver.get("https://www.sitioweb.com/")
```